# actionscript variable name

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I am a freshman for actionscript. I get some code from others and get confused on some syntax.

```
private static var _337833930conversationStartTimeList:ArrayList;
private static var conversationStartTimeList:ArrayList;
```

Whether these two represent same variables or different variables?

I think these should be the different ones but the get and set functions seem also work for the former one.

Does anybody help me to explain why is that and better to give me some references for further study.

Thanks

```
    public static function get conversationStartTimeList() : ArrayList
    {
        return GeneralManager._337833930conversationStartTimeList;
    }// end function

    public static function set conversationStartTimeList(param1:ArrayList) : void
    {
        var _loc_3:IEventDispatcher = null;
        var _loc_2:* = GeneralManager._337833930conversationStartTimeList;
        if (_loc_2 !== param1)
        {
            GeneralManager._337833930conversationStartTimeList = param1;
            _loc_3 = GeneralManager.staticEventDispatcher;
            if (_loc_3 !== null)
            {
                _loc_3.dispatchEvent(PropertyChangeEvent.createUpdateEvent(GeneralManager, "conversationStartTimeList", _loc_2, param1));
            }
        }
        return;
    }// end function
```

Answer (score 0):

These two have different names and they are declared in two separate statements - why would you think they are anything but two separate variables?

Comment: You should also try to not post decompiled code, btw.  If the author doesn't offer any source code, it's probably not intended to be viewed by others.

Comment: Actually in the code, it only has the first statement. But I know that in actionscript, get and set function could access property. But the get and set function's name should be same as the property's name. But in the code, property name is _337833930conversationStartTimeList but function name is conversationStartTimeList. But when I reuse them to test, it works. So I get confused about it. I think the property's name should be also conversationStartTimeList. That is whay I ask whether those two statements represent the same parameter.

Comment: Getter and setter names _should_ be similar, but don't have to be, and they certainly can't be the same as the variable name - there would be a compiler error if they were exactly equal!  So at least, it should be _conversationStartTimeList (starting with an underscore).